# Click event fired when I do drag in chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome

I have a dialog box represented by div and I want to close it when i click somewhere outside from this div.

I use this JQuery code:

```
$(document).bind('click', function(e) {
  var clicked = $(e.target);
  if (!clicked.parents().hasClass("dialog-wrapper")) {
    $('.dialog-wrapper').hide(500);
  }
});
```

Working example is here:

https://jsfiddle.net/ho2p3fnc/

When I click outside of div it works OK. When I click inside of div it works OK.

But when I drag from inside of div to outside and I release mouse button outside it fires click event outside in Chrome

How can I prevent that behavior in chrome?

Comment: Try to use `mouseup` listener instead of `click` (not in drag event)

Comment: I think you're better off having a layer which covers the whole screen underneath the modal. This is what pretty much all modal libraries do and doesn't require anything special other than a normal click event. Also means you can darken the background and clicking outside the modal to close it won't cause unwanted actions by accidentally clicking something they didn't mean to.

Comment: avoid modals / dialog boxes in general.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do it using 2 events. One checking from where the click come from and another which will be triggered on click end. Something like this :

```
var fromDialog = true;

document.addEventListener('mousedown', function(e) {
    var clicked = $(e.target);
    fromDialog = clicked.parents().hasClass("dialog-wrapper");
});

document.addEventListener('mouseup', function(e) {
    if(!fromDialog) {
       $('.dialog-wrapper').hide(500);
    }
});
```